# Problem to understand Lusin theorem.

Tags: measure-theory

**Lusin theorem says:**

> Let $E\subset \mathbb R^d$ measurable and $f$ measurable on $E$ such that $-\infty <f(x)<+\infty $ for all $x\in E$ and $m(E)<+\infty $. For all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a closed set $F_\varepsilon$ with $$F_\varepsilon\subset E\quad\text{and}\quad m(E\setminus F_\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$$ and such that $f|_{F_\varepsilon}$ is continuous.

What about $$x\mapsto \chi_{\mathbb Q\cap [a,b]}(x)\ \ ?$$

I thought that this function was discontinuous everywhere, and thus what would be such an $F_\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: it is continuity with respect to the subspace topology of $F_\epsilon$.

Comment: I don't have anything like that which is precise... But even with the topology induce, I don't see how it can be continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $E=[a,b]$, take $F_\epsilon$ to be a compact subset of $[a,b]\setminus\Bbb Q$ such that $m([a,b]\setminus F_\epsilon)<\epsilon$. Your function restricted to such an $F_\epsilon$ is identically $0$, hence continuous.