# Lusin's theorem counterexample

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $E\subset \mathbb R^d$ measurable and $f$ measurable on $E$ such that $-\infty <f(x)<+\infty $ for all $x\in E$ and $m(E)<+\infty $. For all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a compact set $F_\varepsilon$ with $$F_\varepsilon\subset E\quad\text{and}\quad m(E\setminus F_\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$$ and such that $f|_{F_\varepsilon}$ is continuous.

Definition stolen from this thread: [Problem to understand Lusin theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465844/problem-to-understand-lusin-theorem)

Consider $$x\mapsto \chi_{[0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q}(x)\ \ $$

This is not continuous on $[0,1]$ but continuous on $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q$.
Supposedly this is a counterexample for the fact that we can't choose $\epsilon=0$ May anybody shed some light on this? (Disregarding the fact that in the definition for $\epsilon=0, m(E\setminus F_\varepsilon)<\epsilon$ there would be a contradiction anyway, but it is written like that in my notes)
And is $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ compact? (my guess is yes because it is bounded and closed)
Thx in advance.

Edit: Thanks so far for the answers. Also I made a mistake in the question which I fixed now. (Should have been $[0, 1]\setminus\mathbb Q$ in the function, i.e. $[0,1]$ without the rationals).

Comment: $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ is not closed. It is dense in $ [0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

No, $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ is not closed, and therefore not compact.

If $F \subset E$ is compact and is not all of $E$, then $E \backslash F$ is 
nonempty and open, so $m(E \backslash F) > 0$.  This has very little to do with $f$, except that $f$ is not continuous on $E$ itself so you can't take $F = E$.

Comment: Jup, I made a mistake regarding the function, fixed it now thx.

Answer (score 1):

Is $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$?  I'm not so sure.  Pick your favorite irrational number $x \in (0,1)$.  Then there's a sequence of rationals $p_n \to x$.  Eventually, $0 < p_n < 1$.  Ignoring finitely many terms, we have a sequence $\{p_n\}_n$ in $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ so that $(\lim_n p_n) \notin \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$.

Comment: I see it now thx.